# El significado de "trácate"

Tags: vocabulario

El otro día el gobierno argentino aumentó la tasa que pasó de 60 a casí 70 porcentaje, y desde entonces hay un clip popular en las redes sociales sobre Tato Bores en uno de sus monólogos en los años 60 regañando a los argentinos por comprar el dólar estadounidense "hasta las orejas." Y en el mismo clip Bores dice esto:

> Cuando Boca pierde, el dólar sube tres mangos. El domingo que Boca gana, el dólar sube cuatro mangos. Anuncian frío para agosto y ***¡trácate!***, el dólar se pierde de vista.

Yo sé lo que se trata aquí, que los argentinos compran el dólar sin razón aparente. Pero ¿qué significa trácate? No sé cual es el verbo infinitivo. ¿Sería una jerga que se origina en Argentina? Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG, Tato Bores!!!

*Trácate* no es un verbo, es una onomatopeya utilizada como interjección, bastante antigua y sinónimo de *ñaca*, *ñácate*,  *patapúm*, *pumba*, *zácate*, *zas* utilizadas todas siempre entre signos de admiración.

El significado es algo repentino, sorpresivo, que sucede de golpe y sin aviso.

En la definición de *patapúm* aparece: *sonido de un golpe, de un reventón, o el ruido sordo que produce algo que cae*, y es aplicable a todos sus sinónimos.

En el cuento infantil *[¡Trácate ...eres  un oso!](https://anexoliterario.blogspot.com/2008/05/tracate-eres-un-oso.html)*, el niño protagonista utiliza la palabra *trácate* como *golpe* de magia para transformar en animales a quienes le rodean.

En España se utiliza: *¡toma!* *¿Querías caldo? ¡Toma dos tazas!*

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Añadir a lo que muy bien ha dejado expuesto Danielillo en su respuesta anterior que "¡**trácate**!", es una expresión inventada y popularizada por el dibujante de humor gráfico argentino, Juan Carlos Colombres (Buenos Aires, 1923-2017), conocido como Landrú (*Este apodo "Landrú", fue adoptado, según contó a una revista, porque además nació el día en que guillotinaron en Francia al asesino Landrú*.).

[image: (Landrú)]

Aproximadamente en los años 50 y 60 del siglo pasado junto a la locución "**¡trácate!**", aparecieron y se divulgaron en sus obras otras expresiones que han tenido igualmente gran repercusión y acogida por parte del público como **mersa, tururú y piruja**, llegando desde entonces hasta nuestros días.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landr%C3%BA_(dibujante)